# Writing scripts that use different commands in different shells

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, ksh, portability

How can I write a script that is shell independent? I want to be able to run one script which will run in `ksh`, `sh` and `bash`.

For example: If I have a line in my script like `whence ls` which will run in `ksh` and not in `sh`, I want to be able to have something like

```
if (ksh)
then whence ls
if (sh)
then whereis ls
```

Can I use `$SHELL` value or is there any other way?

Comment: also note that whatever works in sh generally automagically works on "improved" shells like bash and ksh, because it's generally the least common denominator with regards to shell features. the only time you'll really run into trouble with major incompatibilities is if you try to make it run in the csh family.

Comment: While I'm sure such portability is achievable, I believe it's non-trivial to implement. I think you're better off using Perl or Python or similar.

Answer (score 3):

A pattern you'll typically see with Unix shell scripts is the use of a variable for the executables named by their generic function, for example `$ECHO`. You'll then have a top level function or two that will determine what `$ECHO` should be set to.

Once `$ECHO` has been set, then throughout your code you'll see this:

```
$ECHO "hi"
```

This saves you from having to litter your code with lots of if..then..else blocks which have nothing to do with your scripts functionality and only the platform interpreter that it's using.

So you could do the same for any key programs that you're interested in swapping out based on which interpreter/platform you're running on.

```
if (ksh)
then
  ECHO=echo1
  FILEFIND=whence
else if (sh)
  ECHO=echo2
  FILEFIND=whereis
else
  ECHO=echo3
  FILEFIND=which
fi
```

#### Should you do this?

I would say if you're trying to make your script portable and you're concerned with the availability of certain interpreters or executables it's best to code to the lowest common denominator, i.e. `/bin/sh`.

Just look at how Oracle and others do this. They generally provide their installers so that they're scripted in `/bin/sh`. This is the lowest common denominator when you get into supporting across a variety of Unixes such as Solaris, AIX, and Linux.

Take a look at this guide put together by Novell titled: [Making Scripts Portable](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/11232.html). It covers the lineage of the various shells and what the common set of commands are across several of them with tips on how to deal with their subtleties.

Comment: +1 Indeed. I believe this pattern is idiomatic in Makefiles especially.

Answer (score 0):

you might have to accomplish by kicking off another shell process like so ...

```
if [ -x /bin/ksh ]
then
    output=`/bin/ksh whence ls`
fi

if [ -x /bin/sh ]
then
    output=`/bin/sh which ls`
fi
```

Comment: What if all these shells exist? I think you're better off using an `if...elif...else` cascade.

Comment: Besides, are we sure the `if` statement syntax itself will work on all shells?

Comment: why would `if ... elif ... else` be better? Maybe the OP's intent is to see if `whence` and `which` yield different results or wants to do something else entirely.  your are making assumptions about what the OP wants to accomplish.

Comment: I believe that when you say "Maybe the OP's intent is..." you have fallen into the trap of making an assumption yourself, in which case you should mention it in the answer. As to why I believe my assumption is better, it's because of [Occam's Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor).